# alternative bash for windows / or help on cygwin with specific tasks

Tags: windows, bash, shell

my goal: to create a suite of scripts that do some common system tasks, which include these

- copy/move/list/search/grep files
- watch/start/stop processes
- run queries against Oracle via sqlplus

i grew accustomed to using Cygwin/bash to ease my life at work, and frankly speaking, i don't want to move away from bash language and start learning PowerShell, for example - so i started searching for a way to run bash scripts on Windows, ... preferably something alternative to Cygwin.

the truth is that i am still not pleased with Cygwin installation, and the fact that there is no simple way around it, that it is targeting more or less expert users, and there are a number of things that might pop up during the installation. i mean. what i am trying to do now is to write a suite of scripts that will target someone less expert than me (and i am in no way a real expert) - in most cases some kind of an administrator who doesn't want to know the script details.

i am thinking that this user will also want to be able to run these scripts on another machine, and i want to be able to explain him/her how to do it, without just saying, call the support, and, me, eventually (so that we can install cygwin on another machine etc etc.)

i tried MinGW(msys) but it also needs manual steps to set things up - i mean, these manual steps have become something of a de facto standard in these Windows ports (sorry, maybe i have a mood for bragging). win-bash looked like it could be a solution, but i ended up trashing it too, because of the old bash version, and its inability to do things i was able to do in cygwin - specifically

- here documents
- things like "cmd /C dir *" (don't know why) - and yes, i do cmd /C dir in cases i am in some kind of shared network folder with thousands of files, and ls is significantly slower than dir

my questions at last:

- am i doomed to use PowerShell? i guess i will, reluctantly, if i have to
- is there a simple pre-packaged "slim" cygwin installation.. or, portable cygwin, even better? there is a cygwin-portable project on sourceforge, but it's not that doesn't need those manual steps, again, apparently - is there a way to automate those steps, perhaps? and if there is, i wonder why somebody hasn't done it already? - and then, would it be possible to call bash scripts from Windows command prompt using a simple command like "bash somescript.sh"?

thanks for your attention.

Comment: Just use Cygwin, it's really not that bad.

Comment: Are you trying to improve *your* experience using a cygwin like Unix on Windows, or make a package that can be installed for a targeted group of users?

Comment: @shelter i am trying to find an easy and user-friendly way to integrate the ability to run BASH scripts on a Windows machine. you can argue that using "scripts" is not by itself a "final" way to make a user-friendly product - but i was wondering if my quick-n-dirty scripts could be reused by someone else, in a more efficient and easy, and universal way.. i am not even talking about cygwin in particular - just something that would run the scripts.

Comment: a side comment: we finally stuck up with PowerShell for what we wanted to do (stopping/starting/monitoring services), inevitably (my bash/Cygwin attempts were a sort of a kicking - and PS is comparatively straightforward anyway for these tasks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned here](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.setup.html#faq.setup.cli), the Cygwin installation can totally be scripted and parametrized to ran in a silently and automatic mode.

If you define the minimal list of cygwin packages you need, just use a little .bat script that call the cygmin setup executable like this

`setup.exe --packages=list_of_packages_you_need --quiet-mode`

Comment: so yes, that was the way i finally followed, although a bit differently - there is a hint on that same FAQ page about a semi-automated way to install cygwin, using a local download directory. steps:

Comment: 1. i run setup.exe with "download only" option selected, and clicked all "next" through to the end, effectively choosing the default install 2. copied the local install dir (which i renamed to "local") along with setup.exe on a network drive 3. made a batch file (automated_setup.bat) with the following line: `"\\InstallNetworkDir\cygwin\setup.exe" -q -L -l "\\InstallNetworkDir\cygwin\local" -R "c:\cygwin"` - this file can be run from any machine on the same network and it should install cygwin to local c:\cygwin directory

Comment: i subsequently created a scripts directory in Cygwin's /home, where i copied my *.sh scripts. it is possible to create a windows batch wrapper for each script - i made one for testing, and it should contain something like this: `c:\cygwin\bin\bash --login /home/scripts/myscript.sh %1 %2 %3` - i think that --login parameter is necessary for bash to know where .bashrc is stored and map the windows environment options & dirs correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the cygwin install process, it should be tolerable for a less technical user.

The cygwin install can be streamlined using command-line args; 
http://sources.redhat.com/ml/cygwin-apps/2003-03/msg00526.html

You can also automate the install of most cygwin packages through cyg-apt.

Comment: +1 thank you for a fast response and apt-get alternative to setup.exe command-line options, i am accepting the other answer just because it has a more universal link to cygwin documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't verified this but I suspect that msys implements a *nix look alike by creating windows executable versions of system commands. All of the common commands have an executable on my install of msys. If that is true then it should be possible to use them separate from a complete install.

Try copying "bash.exe", "cp.exe", etc. from the msys bin directory to a machine/vm that does not have an msys install and see if it works. You may need to copy some dll's or shared libraries as well. A windows dependency checker program would show which dll's an executable is using.

You could package up the stuff you use and make a simple installer or just copy the files with your scripts.

Comment: +1 indeed copying the MSYS directory from MinGW installation (~20mb) to another machine with no unix-like things installed and simply running bash --login (from the corresponding bin directory) worked just fine. still i had to review the code of the script (which run in cygwin) in a few places, in particular 1) (of course) local drive paths (/c instead of /cygdrive/c) 2) couldn't still find solution to this - a command like `cmd /c dir /b` needs to be written as `cmd /c "dir /b"`, and if i'm using variables to concatenate command strings, things don't seem to work (yet) - but other stuff works

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MKS Toolkit](http://www.mkssoftware.com/products/). Unlike Cygwin, it can live within the Windows world. Files end in CR/LF like Windows files, and you don't have that /cygdrive/c stuff. Naked drive letters work fine in MKS Toolkit.

A few caveats:

- I haven't used MKS Toolkit in a long time. See following reason.
- MKS Toolkit is (sit down for this) $600 per license. Ouch! That's why I use Cygwin even though I don't think it's as good or works as well.
- It's Kornshell based and not Bash (although this may be a bit different). Kornshell and BASH are 95% alike. However, that last 5% gets you. I actually like Kornshell better than BASH in many respects. Kornshell has the `print` statement which is way superior than the `echo` statement. Variable names don't disappear in blocks. You can easily do double loops because almost all the commands can take `unit` numbers of input and output. However, Kornshell doesn't have those neat escape characters in the prompt, and it's hard to find the exit status of a command in the middle of the pipeline.

Comment: yes, that's quite not that affordable for me, but it's interesting to know that there are people who invest seriously into Unix/Windows interoperability, and there's a specific tool and a dedicated support team for them...